# Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Installation error

Tags: visual-studio-2015, installation

I ran into big trouble with Visual Studio 2015. I accidentally deleted Visual Studio 2014 folder in program data. After that I could no longer run it. Then I uninstalled it with other tools and installed, repeating it several times. But every time after installation is complete, when I open Visual Studio 2015 I get error

```
   **An error occurred during installation. Error code:-2147023293.**
```

And Visual Studio 2015 becomes unresponsive. How can I fix this ?

Comment: **`1)`** The quickest way - if you are in a rush - is to install on a virtual to get yourself back up and running. **`2)`** You can also [try a forced cleanup](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/support/vs2015/uninstall-visual-studio-2015/). **`3)`** Or you might succeed installing version 2017 or 2019 instead - who knows? Might be acceptable (usually not). Just off the top of my head before heading out. All I got for now, sorry.

Comment: Just one more (scroll down to read): https://github.com/Microsoft/VisualStudioUninstaller (and [the blog entry](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/setup/removing-visual-studio-components-left-behind-after-an-uninstall/))

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I simply formatted my PC and reinstalled VS2015. That was the quick and neat solution.

Answer (score 0):

> And Visual Studio 2015 becomes unresponsive. How can I fix this ?

**First**, thanks for **Stein** sharing the useful info with us.

According to your issue, you could try these steps:

**1)** Before it, please make sure your Windows is up to date and if not, please try to update it to the latest version.

If the update is corrupted, please refer to [the following guide](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/10164/fix-windows-update-errors
) to fix it.

**2)** open the vs2015 setup program and then click **Repair** option and before it, you should run the program as administrator

**3)** If not, please try to uninstall VS2015 on the **Programs and Features** under **Control Panel** as [Stein suggested](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/support/vs2015/uninstall-visual-studio-2015/) and then reinstall VS2015.

**Note**: you should temporarily turn off any anti-virus software during installation.

During the process, you can collect your installation logs by using [collect.exe tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=12493). Please download and run this , go to `%temp%` folder and find the `vslogs.zip` file, upload it to https://onedrive.live.com/ and share the link in here.